# How do I compare changes in text over time?

Tags: sql, mysql, window-functions, mysql-8.0

I'm not able to quite figure out how to capture the changes over time. I have the following:

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Bjw2PP4Y)

```
CREATE TABLE term_changes (load_id int, merchant_id int, load_date date, terms varchar(50));

INSERT INTO term_changes (load_id, merchant_id, load_date, terms) VALUES 
  (1, 1, '2023-01-05', 'Roses are red'),
  (2, 2, '2023-01-05', 'Roses are blue'),
  (3, 1, '2023-01-06', 'Roses are red'),
  (4, 2, '2023-01-06', 'Roses are blue'),
  (5, 1, '2023-01-07', 'Roses are violet'),
  (6, 2, '2023-01-07', 'Roses are blue'),
  (7, 1, '2023-01-08', 'Roses are violet'),
  (8, 2, '2023-01-08', 'Roses are yellow');

WITH t1 AS (SELECT load_id, merchant_id, load_date, MD5(terms) AS terms
            FROM term_changes
            ORDER BY merchant_id, load_id),
t2 AS (SELECT load_id, 
              merchant_id, 
              load_date, 
              terms, 
              LAG(load_id, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY merchant_id 
                                    ORDER BY load_id) AS prev_load_id
       FROM t1)
SELECT *
FROM   t2 
       JOIN t1 ON t1.load_id = t2.prev_load_id
                  AND t1.merchant_id = t2.merchant_id
                  AND t1.terms != t2.terms
```

Which returns

| load_id | merchant_id | load_date | terms | prev_load_id | load_id | merchant_id | load_date | terms |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 1 | 2023-01-07 | 84df2c2124ad3fc5c8cdf76ce1d7f3e3 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 2023-01-06 | 6becb043847fefb01e7989034cbdb136 |
| 8 | 2 | 2023-01-08 | 90b64ad67da829652ee622e0695748fc | 6 | 6 | 2 | 2023-01-07 | 0e3eb8ff97b31e8874f7b51c23f242a2 |

The output I'm after captures the *current* and *changed* values by `merchant_id`:

| load_id | merchant_id | load_date | terms |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-01-05 | Roses are red |
| 5 | 1 | 2023-01-07 | Roses are violet |
| 2 | 2 | 2023-01-05 | Roses are blue |
| 8 | 2 | 2023-01-08 | Roses are yellow |

- Using `load_id` as there may be multiple entries per date

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I just needed to change to a `LEFT JOIN` move the predicate:

```
CREATE TABLE term_changes (load_id int, merchant_id int, load_date date, terms varchar(50));

INSERT INTO term_changes (load_id, merchant_id, load_date, terms) VALUES 
  (1, 1, '2023-01-05', 'Roses are red'),
  (2, 2, '2023-01-05', 'Roses are blue'),
  (3, 1, '2023-01-06', 'Roses are red'),
  (4, 2, '2023-01-06', 'Roses are blue'),
  (5, 1, '2023-01-07', 'Roses are violet'),
  (6, 2, '2023-01-07', 'Roses are blue'),
  (7, 1, '2023-01-08', 'Roses are violet'),
  (8, 2, '2023-01-08', 'Roses are yellow'),
  (9, 3, '2023-01-05', 'Roses are green'),
  (10, 3, '2023-01-06', 'Roses are green'),
  (11, 3, '2023-01-07', 'Roses are green'),
  (12, 3, '2023-01-08', 'Roses are green');


WITH t1 AS (SELECT load_id, 
                   merchant_id, 
                   load_date, 
                   terms, 
                   MD5(terms) AS terms_hashed
            FROM term_changes
            ORDER BY merchant_id, load_id),
t2 AS (SELECT load_id, 
              merchant_id, 
              load_date, 
              terms, 
              terms_hashed, 
              LAG(load_id, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY merchant_id 
                                    ORDER BY load_id) AS prev_load_id
       FROM t1)
SELECT t2.load_id,
       t2.merchant_id,
       t2.load_date,
       t2.terms
FROM   t2 
       LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.load_id = t2.prev_load_id
                       AND t1.merchant_id = t2.merchant_id
WHERE  ( t1.terms_hashed != t2.terms_hashed
         OR t2.prev_load_id IS NULL )
```

| load_id | merchant_id | load_date | terms |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-01-05 | Roses are red |
| 5 | 1 | 2023-01-07 | Roses are violet |
| 2 | 2 | 2023-01-05 | Roses are blue |
| 8 | 2 | 2023-01-08 | Roses are yellow |
| 9 | 3 | 2023-01-05 | Roses are green |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NE3nwszm)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
WITH t1 AS (
  SELECT 
    load_id, 
    merchant_id, 
    load_date, 
    terms, 
    LAG(terms) OVER (PARTITION BY merchant_id ORDER BY load_date) AS prev_terms
  FROM term_changes
),
t2 AS (
  SELECT 
    load_id, 
    merchant_id, 
    load_date, 
    terms 
  FROM t1 
  WHERE prev_terms IS NULL OR prev_terms != terms
)
SELECT *
FROM t2
ORDER BY merchant_id, load_date;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pedPy3Tl)

Answer (score 0):

You are making it much much more complicated than it need to be.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5ZziWlDy)

```
select load_id, merchant_id, load_date, terms, unchanged
from (
    select load_id, merchant_id, load_date, terms,
        coalesce(terms = lag(terms) over (partition by merchant_id order by load_id), 0) unchanged
    from term_changes
) term_changes_plus
where not unchanged
order by merchant_id, load_id
```